# Selecting minimum and grouping

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following table:

```
id | product_id | quantity
--------------------------
1  | 222        | 25       
2  | 222        | 35
3  | 223        | 10
```

Now I want to select the lowest quantities grouped by product_id. In SQL this works as

```
SELECT product_id, MIN(quantity) FROM my_table GROUP BY product_id
```

The result of this query is the following

```
product_id | MIN(quantity)
--------------------------
222        | 25
223        | 10
```

However, how can I use Django's database models to do the same?

I tried

```
myModel.objects.filter(product__in=product_ids).annotate(Min("quantity")).values_list("product", "quantity__min")
```

This returns the full table.

Answer (score 1):

```
objects = (MyModel.objects
           .values('product')
           .annotate(Min('quantity'))
           # if you want to get values_list
           .values_list('product', 'quantity__min'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#values